# Cómo puedo verificar en el render que un elemento está vacío (React Native)

Tags: react-native

Tengo un archivo `json` pero a veces este archivo no tiene la imagen.

A veces este item del archivo  está vacío:`item.better_featured_image.media_details.sizes.medium.source_url`

```
 render() {
    const { loading, posts } = this.state;
    if (loading) {
      return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <Text>Cargando .....</Text>
        </View>
      );
    }
    categorie_title = this.props.navigation.getParam("categorie_name");
    return (
      <View>
        <FlatList
          data={this.state.posts}
          renderItem={({ item }) => (
            <TouchableOpacity
              onPress={() =>
                this.props.navigation.navigate("Noticia", {
                  post_id: item.id,
                })
              }
            >
              <Card>
                <Card.Content>
                  <Title>{item.title.rendered}</Title>
                </Card.Content>                    
                <Card.Cover
                  source={{
                    uri:
                      item.better_featured_image.media_details.sizes.medium
                        .source_url
                  }}
                />
                <Card.Content>
                  <HTML html={item.excerpt.rendered} />
                </Card.Content>
              </Card>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          )}
          keyExtractor={item => item.id.toString()}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
```

Solo necesito un condicional - `if`.

La pregunta era si este componente `item.better_featured_image.media_details.sizes.medium.source_url` está vacío, no muestre la imagen.

Esta pregunta también esta en el sitio en ingles:
https://stackoverflow.com/q/59904929/2400373

Este es el error:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Esta pregunta la coloque en el sitio en ingles y conseguí la respuesta, la traduzco y la pongo aqui seguro puede ser de ayuda: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59905061/2400373

Cuando estés en JSX, no olvides que todavía puedes utilizar javascript, así que solo agrega un condicional:

```
              <Card>
                <Card.Content>
                  <Title>{item.title.rendered}</Title>
                </Card.Content>        
                {/* Aqui se coloca el condicional si no viene información */}
                {item.better_featured_image ?              
                (<Card.Cover
                  source={{
                    uri:
                      item.better_featured_image.media_details.sizes.medium
                        .source_url
                  }}
                />) : null}
                <Card.Content>
                  <HTML html={item.excerpt.rendered} />
                </Card.Content>
              </Card>
```